# How do you get the systemctl Result for a failed service from Python?

Tags: python, systemd

If a systemd service unit is in a failed state, systemctl status shows that fact:

```
    # systemctl status myservice
    ● myservice.service - Important Crash Prone service (myservice)
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2017-08-22 20:04:13 UTC; 3s ago
      Process: 31108 ExecStart=/bin/myservice (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
     Main PID: 31108 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
```

I'd like to have a Python program get that "Result: start-limit" field without forking `systemctl` and attempting to parse the output. The other fields (e.g. Loaded, Active) are available from the Python dbus library.

For instance, the following code gets the `ActiveState` property which is displayed by `systemctl` after "Active:" (the word "failed" in the output above).

```
from dbus import Interface, SystemBus, SessionBus
bus = SystemBus()
systemd = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1',
                         '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')

manager = Interface(systemd, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager')

myservice_unit = manager.LoadUnit('myservice.service')

myservice_proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1', str(myservice_unit))

myservice = Interface(myservice_proxy, 
dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit')

prop = 'ActiveState'
value = myservice_proxy.Get('org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit',
                            prop,
                            dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
print("{} is: {}".format(prop, value))
```

It appears the "Result" value is not a property in the sense that much of the other output is.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/, it explains the `Result` being part of *Service Unit Objects* (`org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service`).

So, I added this to your code:

```
if value == 'failed':
    result_prop = 'Result'
    result = myservice_proxy.Get('org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service',
                                 result_prop,
                                 dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
    print(result)
```

Now it's working beautifully!